# Regex remove decimal only if whole number

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

I'm looking to take a percentage and strip the decimal, %, and round up if needed. Unless it's only a decimal in which case just strip the %. I also have a special case of `<1%` which I may just deal with separately. So we start with `[<]|[\.]+[\d]*|%$` which removes the decimal and the %. But doesn't round, and takes out the `.5%`. I'm not sure what or how to add something to fix this. Is it even possible?

I need:

```
'.5%'   to .5  
'0%'    to  0  
'<1%'   to .1  
'65%'   to 65  
'65.5%' to 66  
'65.4%' to 65
```

Comment: No need Regex. Remove the  `%` convert to `float/double` and then use a `CASE` to format output.

Comment: `0.5%` is less than `1%` why is `.5` and not `.1` as 3rd sample.?

Comment: Thanks Juan Carlos, I'll do that I think I was just stuck because it's a set of strings, with the possibility of actual string text which I'm dealing with in a CASE and felt the need to handle the "numbers" all as one

Because the people giving me data are silly and I'm getting the literal string `<1%` which I've been told to convert into .1, while `.5%`, etc is still a possibility.

Comment: `<1%` is the only literal? I make an edit to make it clear you have string and want numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

- cte are the test cases

  - in the sql demo have to use `,` as decimal separator.
- clean the string

  - remove the `%` character
  - handle the special literal '<1%'
  - convert to float
- Final query return the number with decimals if `< 1` but round the bigger numbers

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/FWA24890)**

```
WITH cte(item) as (
    SELECT ',5%' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '0%' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '<1%' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '65%' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '65,5%' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '65,4%' FROM DUAL      
), clean as (
    SELECT item, CASE WHEN item = '<1%' THEN 0.1
                      ELSE CAST(REPLACE(item, '%')  AS float) 
                 END as flt
    FROM cte   
)
SELECT item, 
       flt,    
        CASE WHEN flt = 0 then 0   -- no need this one is also handle for the next case
             WHEN flt < 1 then flt                               
             ELSE ROUND(flt)
        END as final
FROM clean
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it.  Use TRANSLATE() to replace the less than sign with a decimal and remove the percent sign at the same time.  Round if over 1.

```
SQL> with tbl(data) as (
     select '.5%'   from dual union
     select '0%'    from dual union
     select '<1%'   from dual union
     select '65%'   from dual union
     select '65.5%' from dual union
     select '65.4%' from dual
   )
   select data BEFORE,
          case
            when translate(data, '<%', '.') < 1
              then to_char(cast(translate(data, '<%', '.') as float))
            when translate(data, '<%', '.') > 1
              then to_char(round(cast(replace(data, '%') as float)))
          end  AFTER
   from tbl;

BEFOR AFTER
----- ----------------------------------------
.5%   .5
0%    0
65%   65
65.4% 65
65.5% 66
<1%   .1

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```